# Updating to EE 2.9.2 on WAMP, blank screen after terms & conditions

Tags: update, install

I've upgraded EE our production and QA environments with no problem (both IIS), but when I tried to upgrade EE on my local environment (WAMP 2.2), I get stuck with this screen after accepting the terms and conditions:

[image: blank screen during EE update]

Anyone else encounter this? How did you get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since posting my question, I haven't figured out *why* this happened, but I did come up with a workaround for it:

1. Import your upgraded production environment's MySQL database on your local environment*
2. Follow the [update instructions from EllisLab](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html) up to but not including step 6.
3. Change `$config['app_version']` in `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` to `292`
4. Delete the `system/installer` folder
5. Open your ExpressionEngine CP and you should be running 2.9.2 as you hoped and dreamed

*If importing a dump of your production DB isn't something you normally do, be aware that the following things will need to be updated after you complete your import:

- **DB:** `channel_url` in `exp_channels` (for each channel), example query:

  ```
  UPDATE `[YOUR DB NAME]`.`exp_channels` SET `channel_url`='[YOUR URL]' WHERE `channel_id`='[YOUR CHANNEL ID]';
  ```
- **DB:** `server_path` in `exp_upload_prefs` for each upload destination, example query:

  ```
  UPDATE `[YOUR DB NAME]`.`exp_upload_prefs` SET `server_path`='[YOUR LOCAL PATH]', `url`='[YOUR LOCAL URL]' WHERE `id`='[YOUR UPLOAD DESTINATION ID]';
  ```
- **CP:** URL to the root directory of your site in `Admin > General Config`
- **CP:** Theme Folder Path in `Admin > General Config`
- **CP:** Server path to site's templates in `Design > Templates > Global Template Preferences`
- **CP:** File path in `Add-Ons > Extensions > Low Variables > Extension Settings`

These are the things we have to update in our setup, so your milage may vary. Godspeed.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar - possibly a plugin not responding. Remove third-party plugins in your system folder, try updating again and then return your plugins...you should update fine, and then you'll need the third-party items back in to open the control panel.

Comment: Good point. I'm inclined to think that this is not the case here, only because the update worked as expected on the production environment (our production server matches each local environment in nearly every way).